# Washed out/ Beige Images in Tensorboard using Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard, tfrecord

I'm testing out [this object detection implementation](https://github.com/SJTU-Thinklab-Det/DOTA-DOAI/tree/master/FPN_Tensorflow) on a small subset of the DOTA dataset using Google Colab. The training is going fine, but the the images in Tensorboard are washed out and beige. Could there be an issue with the images when they converted to a tfrecord, or is there some issue with Tensorboard/ Colab compatibility? I'm using tensorflow-gpu = 1.13.1 & tensorboard 1.13.1. See below screenshot for commands I used to open tensorboard and the issues with the images.

[image: b]

Answer (score 0):

There was in fact a problem with image normalization caused bu user error editing code.